# addrecords event doesn't work on Sencha Touch store

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

here is my code

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: ['name', {
            name: 'twitter',
            type: 'string'
        }]
    }
});

Ext.define('Fiddle.MyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        model: 'MyModel',
        listeners: {

        }
    },
     addrecords: function(store, records, eOpts) {
                console.log('new recorded have been added.');
                console.log('new recorded number = ' + store.getCount());
            }
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', 'Welcome to Sencha Fiddle!');
        var mystore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            data: [{
                name: 'Mitchell Simoens',
                twitter: 'SenchaMitch'
            }, {
                name: 'Jay Garcia',
                twitter: 'ModusJeasus'
            }, {
                name: 'Anthony De Moss',
                twitter: 'ademoss1'
            }]

        });


        mystore.add({
            name: "winston fan",
            twitter: 'WFC'
        });

        //console.log('mystore has ' + mystore.getCount());
    }
});
```

and here is the sencha fiddle :
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/6d1

I know I can use mystore.on() to bind the event, but it's hard to do it in my case. So I'd like to put the addrecords into the config of the store. But no matter where I put the code

```
   addrecords: function(store, records, eOpts) {
                console.log('new recorded have been added.');
                console.log('new recorded number = ' + store.getCount());
            }
```

either in listeners under config section, or directly under the store, the addrecords event doesn't get triggered. It is only triggered when I use mystore.on('addrecords', function() {}); .

Can anyone tell me how to put the event in the config of the store?

thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Events in config of the store are a bad idea, as they can be easily overriden, but they go inside listeners. listeners: { addrecords: function() {...} }

Really, a controller should add the listener using store.on('addrecords', function ....)

(and of course the framework is working; your code is broken ;-) )

Comment: hi Shepsii, have you tried to put the addrecords inside listeners under config? I tried and it doesn't work.

Comment: You are aware that the store you have defined as Fiddle.MyStore has no relevance to the rest of your code? Ext.create('Ext.data.Store'... is used later on not Ext.create('Fiddle.MyStore'

Thanks for the downvote on the answer whoever that was - care to explain?

Comment: hi @shepsii, thanks to your reply. I guess the reason why you said "Fiddle.MyStore has no relevance to the rest of your code" is because they don't use the same "namespace". But even I changed code to make them under same namespace and moved addrecords into listeners, it still doesn't work. I have tried both ways. Have you tried it? Can you please provide a sencha fiddler to prove your approach work?

Comment: Hi Franva. You are defining a class Fiddle.MyStore and then not using that class at all, except reverting to Ext.data.Store. I'm not want to "prove" that defining a class and then using it is a reasonable and effective approach to coding.

I'll repeat what I said on the sencha forums... I think you need to have a read of some Sencha Touch books and get a basic understanding of best practices of the framework. The problems you come across demonstrate a lack of understanding of how it works from the ground up and I think reading some best practices would be of a huge help to you.

Comment: hi shepsii, I got your point. I defined a store but didn't use it, so the even wasn't fired. Thank you.

Comment: Cool, glad to hear that's of use! It might be useful to your programming to try splitting each store/view/controller/model into its own file. If you need help on how to do this, let me know. It really helps in terms of thinking about Sencha Touch as a class based framework.

Comment: Exactly! I have my several views in different js files, which is where I like Sencha Touch. Thank you. Do you have any recommended books to read? I found several, but they are all out of date, e.g. Sencha Touch in Action. Seems no new and detailed books for Sencha Touch.

Comment: Yes - hopefully this is of help! https://www.joshmorony.com/beginners-guide-to-sencha-touch/